# How do I use/load a large quantity of images without the webpage crashing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, image, web

I'm building a very small SPA (angular) website, put it has a large number of mid-quality images.
At the moment, when I have more than ~15 on the site, and go through viewing each of them (the site is a sort of image gallery), the page/tab/browser crashes.

How can I effectively manage this, so that more images can be used. Is there a way to unload images from the browser memory?

Comment: This is impossible to diagnose with the details given, as commented its unlikely to be related to that small number of images.

Comment: I don't think a webpage with 15 images is cause for concern. Pages with 1500 images are loaded and displayed just fine daily. The problem must be somewhere else, try to provide us with more details. That said, the "too many images"-problem _is_ real, and can be solved through JavaScript for instance, at least. But again, "too many images" may vary, you need to profile the page+browser+platform to see whether it is a problem first.